# How to manage versions in VS2010?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

For example after I build the Release version I want it name changed to (for example) **MyApp-1.2.exe**. After I build the next version I want the exe to be named **MyApp-1.3.exe**. I still want to be able to run the **MyApp-1.2.exe**.

I would rather not use any external tool(I know there are nAnt and nMaven) and do it in VS. IF its not possible than I bet nAnt is the better option for me.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for source control? Because you're not only going to want to run the older release - you're going to want to look at the old sources.

Comment: @John Saunders I was taught to not put binaries under source control. I bet nMaven has great versioning support, but I don't want to depend on a lot of outside projects(In Java when you deploy a Maven version it creates also zip file with sources).

Comment: I meant to put the sources under source control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it also via MSBuild with the help of the [GetAssemblyIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164296.aspx) task:

```
<GetAssemblyIdentity
  AssemblyFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\src\MyApp\bin\MyApp.exe">
  <Output
    TaskParameter="Assemblies"
    ItemName="AssemblyIdentities"/>
</GetAssemblyIdentity>
```

And then rename your .exe file:

```
<Copy 
    SourceFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\src\MyApp\bin\MyApp.exe" 
    DestinationFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\src\MyApp\bin\MyApp-(AssemblyIdentities.Version).exe"></Copy>
<Delete
    Files="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\src\MyApp\bin\MyApp.exe"></Delete>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do it in VS, you can (again) do it using the **Post-build Command** function (from `Project properties` -> `Build Events`).

Running a script or batch file that will `copy` the file and then rename it. I used to do it based on current date (not version) a few years back (not even sure why).

You can do virtually anything in the build events if you can create batch files or scripts.

Using a build system is IMHO preferable to this approach.